# Why does the constructor of my static class never seem to get called?

Tags: c#, static, console

I'm writing a Console application in C#. When the application is run I need it to check a few things before doing any work such as whether certain settings and directories exist. I have a static class for this stored in `Logging.cs` and I have put the checks in the constructor for this class but it never seems to get called.

Here's a very basic example:

**Program.cs**

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started application");
        Console.ReadKey(); // Stops the application exiting so I can read the output
    }
}
```

**Logging.cs**

```
internal static class Logging
{
    static Logging()
    {
        // The checks are all here, for the demo we'll just use WriteLine
        Console.WriteLine("Logging constructor");
    }
}
```

Expected console output:

> Started application
>   Logging constructor   <-- This line never appears

I know I could create a static method inside the `Logging` class called `DoStartupChecks` and call it from `Main` in Program.cs, but I want to understand what I've done wrong here. Maybe the answer is to create the method and call it but I want to understand why the above example is wrong first.

Comment: Are you accessing the class at all?

Comment: Static constructor gets called the first time the class is used, not when your program is loaded. So your example would indeed not cause the constructor to be called.

Comment: OK that makes sense. I thought that making it static would create an instance and therefore call the constructor. This makes more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The static constructor is called when a class is referenced the very first time, e.g. by calling any of its members, by creating an instance of it or by calling a method on it.

Thus you have to write something like this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Logging.DoSomething();
    Console.WriteLine("Started application");
    Console.ReadKey(); // Stops the application exiting so I can read the output
}
```

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k9x6w0hc%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> It [the static constructor] is called automatically before the first instance is created or any
>   static members are referenced.

Comment: So I guess I do need a method after all and by calling the method it would also cause the constructor to be called?

Comment: Method, constant, property, field... it could be anything.

Comment: Cool, that makes sense to me. I mistakenly thought that making it static would be enough. Thanks. (I have to wait to accept).